# Find http:// and or www. and strip from domain. leaving domain.com

Tags: python, url, urlparse

I'm quite new to python. I'm trying to parse a file of URLs to leave only the domain name.

some of the urls in my log file begin with http:// and some begin with www.Some begin with both.

This is the part of my code which strips the http:// part. What do I need to add to it to look for both http and www. and remove both?

```
line = re.findall(r'(https?://\S+)', line)
```

Currently when I run the code only http:// is stripped. if I change the code to the following:

```
line = re.findall(r'(https?://www.\S+)', line)
```

Only domains starting with both are affected.
I need the code to be more conditional.
TIA

edit... here is my full code...

```
import re
import sys
from urlparse import urlparse

f = open(sys.argv[1], "r")

for line in f.readlines():
 line = re.findall(r'(https?://\S+)', line)
 if line:
  parsed=urlparse(line[0])
  print parsed.hostname
f.close()
```

I mistagged by original post as regex. it is indeed using urlparse.

Comment: Just a note: You do realise that `www.domain.com` is *different* from `domain.com`, right, and may point at wildly different IPs?

Comment: What about the domains `www.www.com` and `www.com`?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521592/get-root-domain-of-link

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569137/how-to-get-domain-name-from-url I'll delete my existing post now that I can comment :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do without regexes here.

```
with open("file_path","r") as f:
    lines = f.read()
    lines = lines.replace("http://","")
    lines = lines.replace("www.", "") # May replace some false positives ('www.com')
    urls = [url.split('/')[0] for url in lines.split()]
    print '\n'.join(urls)
```

Example file input:

```
http://foo.com/index.html
http://www.foobar.com
www.bar.com/?q=res
www.foobar.com
```

Output:

```
foo.com
foobar.com
bar.com
foobar.com
```

**Edit:**

There could be a tricky url like foobarwww.com, and the above approach would strip the www. We will have to then revert back to using regexes.

Replace the line `lines = lines.replace("www.", "")` with `lines = re.sub(r'(www.)(?!com)',r'',lines)`. Of course, every possible TLD should be used for the not-match pattern.

Comment: @DSM Don't worry, it isn't in use ;)

Comment: Thanks, That works :) Any idea how I can remove everything after the .co.uk/.com etc?

Comment: I didn't get what you mean by everything. Can you explain by an example?

Comment: sure. some urls are links to pages. so in the case of foo.com/index.htm i would like to be left with just foo.com

Comment: That's fantastic, works as I wanted it to. many many thanks. Sorry to be a pain, I find the docs for python difficult to understand. could you perhaps explain some of the amendments you made to your code to give me some idea of how it works? thanks again.

Comment: About the edit: even better just look at the beginning of the string `lines = re.sub(r'(^www.)',r'',lines)` so not only works for `.com`.

Answer (score 21):

It might be overkill for this specific situation, but i'd generally use [`urlparse.urlsplit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlsplit) (Python 2) or [`urllib.parse.urlsplit`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/urllib.parse.html?highlight=urllib.parse#urllib.parse.urlsplit) (Python 3).

```
from urllib.parse import urlsplit  # Python 3
from urlparse import urlsplit  # Python 2
import re

url = 'www.python.org'

# URLs must have a scheme
# www.python.org is an invalid URL
# http://www.python.org is valid

if not re.match(r'http(s?)\:', url):
    url = 'http://' + url

# url is now 'http://www.python.org'

parsed = urlsplit(url)

# parsed.scheme is 'http'
# parsed.netloc is 'www.python.org'
# parsed.path is None, since (strictly speaking) the path was not defined

host = parsed.netloc  # www.python.org

# Removing www.
# This is a bad idea, because www.python.org could 
# resolve to something different than python.org

if host.startswith('www.'):
    host = host[4:]
```

Comment: Doesn't immediately work for URLs starting without 'http://'. `urlparse.urlsplit("www.foo.com").netloc` will return `''`.

Comment: Yes, that's because ``www.foo.com`` is not a valid URL.

Comment: The problem is that some of the urls in OP's file are of this format.

Comment: Trying to mutate a `SplitResult.netloc` this way will result in an `AttributeError` being raised. In order to change `netloc` you will need to use `_replace` like so `replaced = parsed._replace(netloc=host[4:])`

Comment: I'm not changing `netloc`. Am I?

Answer (score 6):

I came across the same problem. This is a solution based on regular expressions:

```
>>> import re
>>> rec = re.compile(r"https?://(www\.)?")

>>> rec.sub('', 'https://domain.com/bla/').strip().strip('/')
'domain.com/bla'

>>> rec.sub('', 'https://domain.com/bla/    ').strip().strip('/')
'domain.com/bla'

>>> rec.sub('', 'http://domain.com/bla/    ').strip().strip('/')
'domain.com/bla'

>>> rec.sub('', 'http://www.domain.com/bla/    ').strip().strip('/')
'domain.com/bla'
```

Answer (score 4):

Check out the [urlparse library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html), which can do these things for you automatically.

```
>>> urlparse.urlsplit('http://www.google.com.au/q?test')
SplitResult(scheme='http', netloc='www.google.com.au', path='/q', query='test', fragment='')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [urlparse](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html). Also, the solution should be generic to remove things other than 'www' before the domain name (i.e., handle cases like server1.domain.com). The following is a quick try that should work:

```
from urlparse import urlparse

url = 'http://www.muneeb.org/files/alan_turing_thesis.jpg'

o = urlparse(url)

domain = o.hostname

temp = domain.rsplit('.')

if(len(temp) == 3):
    domain = temp[1] + '.' + temp[2]

print domain
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe @Muneeb Ali is the nearest to the solution but the problem appear when is something like frontdomain.domain.co.uk....

I suppose:

```
for i in range(1,len(temp)-1):
    domain = temp[i]+"."
domain = domain + "." + temp[-1]
```

Is there a nicer way to do this?